# Is there a list of documentation for the properties on the objects used in auto completion?

Tags: ace-editor

I'm working on setting up an auto completion list and I've been trying to figure out what each property does. Is there more documentation on this object?

Here's what I have so gathered far:

```
public class AutoCompleteObject {

    public function AutoCompleteObject(name:String = null, metadata:String = null) {
        this.value = name;
        meta = metadata;
    }

    /**
     * Value written upon auto completion
     * 
     * @see #caption
     * */
    public var value:String;

    /**
     * The caption is what is shown in the auto completion list as you type the value
     * 
     * @see #value
     * */
    public var caption:String;

    /**
     * The score is a reason unknown 
     * */
    public var score:String;

    /**
     * What is shown to the right of the value or caption if set in the auto complete list
     * 
     * */
    public var meta:String;

    /**
     * Unknown
     * */
    public var className:String;

    /**
     * Unknown
     * */
    public var matchMask:Object;

    /**
     * Unknown
     * */
    public var exactMatch:Object;

    /**
     * Unknown
     * Option: "rightAlignedText"
     * */
    public var type:String;

}
```

Here's my function for getting autocompletion objects:

```
public function getObjectsFromArray(values:Array, metadataType:String = "attribute", className:String = null):Array {
    var newValues:Array = [];
    var numberOfItems:int = values ? values.length :0;
    var autoCompleteObject:AutoCompleteObject;
    var testing:Boolean;
    var object:Object;

    for (var i:int = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
        if (testing) {
            object = {"value":values[i], meta:metadataType};
            newValues.push(object);
        }
        else {
            autoCompleteObject = new AutoCompleteObject(values[i], metadataType);
            autoCompleteObject.className = className;
            autoCompleteObject.type = "attribute";
            newValues.push(autoCompleteObject);
        }
    }

    return newValues;
}
```

My question is what do the following properties mean:

- score (I'm guessing it's a weighted value)
- className
- type

Less important:

- matchMask
- exactMatch

My related questions, if they should be separate questions let me know, are:
 - if class name is what I think it is can I show className in the autocomplete list?
 - can I sort the list by meta type? so my list is above the built in list? 
 - Should the strongly typed object I'm using be changed to dynamic type for future proofing? I found the other properties mentioned because errors were thrown when I changed from using Object.

I can post these as separate questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`score` is a number used for sorting https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.6/lib/ace/autocomplete.js#L494
`matchMask` and `exactMatch` are internal properties used by the sorting algorithm

className is added to the row as a class name https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.6/lib/ace/autocomplete/popup.js#L190

type is a custom property used only by snippet completer https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.6/lib/ace/ext/language_tools.js#L67